# Determine what is causing suspicious request by curl.exe to a remote ip address

Tags: windows, networking, ip, malware, curl

I am using windows firewall control (Binisoft/malwarebytes). The profile is set to block all network requests unless explicitly allowed.

In the firewall connections log I recently noticed the curl.exe file located in windows/system32 is sending a request to a remote ip address "47.75.19.141"

On running a Whois scan on the IP address the following information is revealed:

**IP Whois report**

Alibaba.com LLC AL-3 (NET-47-74-0-0-1) 47.74.0.0 - 47.87.255.255
ALICLOUD-HK ALICLOUD-HK (NET-47-75-0-0-1) 47.75.0.0 - 47.75.255.255

**47.75.19.141 Scan Report**

ASN Owner   Alibaba (US) Technology Co., Ltd.
ISP Alibaba
Continent   Asia
Country Code    Flag (HK) Hong Kong

I am concerned why my pc is sending requests to this remote address via the curl.exe, being somehow related to the Alibaba group in Hongkong. To the best of my knowledge I do not have any software installed that should be making any such request. I did recently install a software that I have learned is developed by a team based in Honkong, but I do not suspect it to have any malicious intent since it is widely used by many industry professionals.

I would like to know if it is possible to perform a trace as to which executable file on my PC is making use of the curl.exe file to make the remote connection.

Thanking you,
Sincerely

Comment: Alibaba offers cloud services much like Amazon, Google and Microsoft. // You have to inspect the URL, otherwise further investigation is not possible.

Comment: @DanielB Thankyou, I would appreciate any advice on what method should be used for inspecting the url? And if it is possible to determine which application has made use of curl.exe to connect to the remote ip in question?

Comment: Hmm, a curl in system32? Sounds a bit suspicious to me.

Comment: @TomYan I had thought the same, although I have read some sources online, which state some builds of windows 10 after a certain date include a native curl.exe (and tar.exe ) in C:\Windows\System32, due to this I was wondering if there is some event log that monitored which application was using this curl.exe in system32, I could then trace it to any suspicious software or malware.

Comment: You could probably use Process Explorer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: @SimonS Thankyou, From my understanding process explorer will display handles/dll files a currently running process has loaded. For this, the process will a) have to be running and b) you will need to know before hand which process to check for. In my case this is an unknown application that may or may not be running and, im guessing it launches the curl.exe file, attempts to connect to the remote ip and then closes the curl.exe. So the curl.exe will not be in running long enough to catch it manually. I was hoping to log all instances the curl.exe launches and which application launched it.

Comment: @SimonS  Thank you for the recommendation, I do not understand how to utilize process explorer as of yet and not certain if this might be possible. Meanwhile I do suspect a particular application, and I will watch its behavior based on launching the application and the time stamp the curl.exe is blocked by the firewall.